# Vuetify treeview search behavior

Tags: search, vue.js, treeview, vuetify.js

Hello and Happy new Year guys,

Again I ask about v-treeview search. When I do my filter, the behavior do not satisfy me.

I updated my version of vuetify to 1.4.0. And I'm using vue 2.5.15

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PXeMmy?&editors=101

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <v-container grid-list-md>
    <v-layout wrap>
      <v-flex xs6>
     <!-- Search Field -->
    <v-text-field label="search" v-model="search" box>
      </v-text-field>
  <!-- Treeview -->
  <v-treeview :items="filteredTree"
              v-model="selected"
                active-class="grey lighten-4 indigo--text"
              item-key="name"
                selected-color="blue"
                selectable
                hoverable>
    </v-treeview>
        </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs6>
        <v-chip v-for="(s , i) in selected" :key="i">
          {{s}}
        </v-chip>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</div>
```

JS :

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return{
      search: '',
      tree: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Applications',
          children: [
            { id: 2, name: 'Calendar' },
            { id: 3, name: 'Chrome' },
            { id: 4, name: 'Webstorm' }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: 'Languages',
          children: [
            { id: 6, name: 'English' },
            { id: 7, name: 'French' },
            { id: 8, name: 'Spannish' }
          ]
        }

      ],
      selected: []
    }
  },
  computed:{
    filteredTree: {
       get: function() {
        let regexp = new RegExp(this.search, "i")
        return this.filterTree(this.tree, regexp) || []
      },
    },
   },
   methods: {
    filterTree: function(tree, filter) {
      if (!Array.isArray(tree)) return null
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tree)).filter(function matchName(o) {
        let temp;
        if (o.name.match(filter)) {
          return true;
        }
        if (!Array.isArray(o.children)) {
          return false;
        }
        temp = o.children.filter(matchName);
        if (temp.length) {
          o.children = temp;
          return true;
        }
      });
  }
   }
})
```

In this exemple when I search "Calen", only "Application -> Calendar" is visible. Until now, it's what I want.

But when I select Calendar, "Application" is also selected; and when I clear the filter, all the children of "Application" are selected too. And I'd like to select "Calendar" and when I clear I don't want its siblings to be selected.

Thank you for reading

Comment: I presume this might be tricky, because presumably if for example you search `Cal` and then select  `Calendar`, then since it's the only filtered option left, `Application` is ticked and marks that item as if All children are selected as well, thus any children you add will be automatically ticked i.e. selected. Thus the only "simple" solution that comes to my mind would actually be HIDING the children from display instead of removing them from array (e.g. set `hidden: true` when filtered)... I'm not sure tho how would you achieve that because apparently there is no `item` slot for example...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try thi when I have free time.  It seems that they work on a filter feature  : https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5621.
I hope an easy solution will come out

Comment: Yeah well there is nothing to try right now I guess... Follow that github issue for now. I don't think it's possible right now, but maybe someone else could jump in and help you with this.